# Solr porter streaming not returning results

Tags: solr

My schema is below. I have added PorterStemFilterFactory to schema.xml. I tried to restart it and reimport but not working:

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" tokenizerFactory="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Comment: what is the error are you getting or what do you mean by not working?

Comment: I have indexed "run" keyword now i am searching "running" and it is not returning any result. According to porter streaming it should return after search like "runs", "running" etc.

Comment: check the same in solr analysis tool...whats text is been indexed and queried...

Comment: I am not seeing PorterStemFilterFactory in solr analysis tool. I am seeing only ST, SF and LCF

Comment: Did you reindex your data?

Comment: Have you reloaded the core after changing the schema?

Comment: Yes, I reindex my Data and reload my core. But still not working